# Django: DeleteView + HttpResponseNotAllowed

Tags: python, django

I found this DeleteView. Anyone can tell me what `return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])`is for? Should I add it to my own DeleteView as well?

```
class DiscountDelete(AdminPermissionRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Discount

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Django's class based views you can define a class variable for this;

```
class DiscountDelete(AdminPermissionRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Discount
    http_method_names = ['post']
```

Then if that view receives a `get` request it'll send back the 405 you're looking for.

Docs on this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.http_method_names

Comment: Ah perfect. I found on Classy CBV this way to write it: `http_method_names = [u'get', u'post', u'put', u'patch', u'delete', u'head', u'options', u'trace'] ` Do you know what the u stands for?

Comment: @JonProgrammer `u''` is a unicode string. You might see this if you're using python 2 and have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` then print a string.

Answer (score 3):

With the usual delete view, when you do a GET request you get a confirmation page. Then when you submit the form with a POST request, the object is deleted.

The custom `get()` method is disabling GET requests. Perhaps it's not needed, because the delete requests are submitted from a different view (e.g. a list view).

We can't tell whether or not you should add this functionality to your delete view. It's up to you.